# How to store option data in mongo?

Tags: mongodb

I have a site that I'm using Mongo on.  So far everything is going well.  I've got several fields that are static option data, for example a field for animal breeds and another field for animal registrars.

**Breeds**

```
Arabian
Quarter Horse
Saddlebred
```

**Registrars**

```
AQHA
American Arabians
```

There are maybe 5 or 6 different collections like this that range from 5-15 elements.

What is the best way to put these in Mongo?  Right now, I've got a separate collection for each group.  That is a breeds collection, a registrars collection etc.

Is that the best way, or would it make more sense to have a single static data collection with a "type" field specifying the option type?

Or something else completely different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this data is static then it's better to just embed the data in documents. This way you don't have to do manual joins.

And also store it in a separate collection (one or several, doesn't matter, choose what's easier) to facilitate presentation (render combo-boxes, etc.)

Comment: Thanks. I store the selected value in the document (that is the animal has a "Registrar" field with a value like "AQHA".)  Wasn't sure if there was a best practice for these type of collections.

Answer (score 3):

I believe creating multiple collections has collection size implications? (something about MongoDB creating a collection file on disk as twice the size of the previous file [ db.0 = 64MB, db.1 = 128MB and so on)

Here's what I can think of:

**1. Storing as single collection**

The benefits here are:

- You only need one call to Mongo to fetch, and if you can cache the call you quickly have the data.
- You avoid duplication: create a single schema that deals with all your options. You can just nest suboptions if there are any.
- Of course, you also avoid duplication in statics/methods to modify options.

I have something similar on a project that I'm working on. I have categories and subcategories all stored in one collection. Here's a JSON/BSON dump as example:

In all the data where I need to store my 'options' (station categories in my case) I simply use the _id.

```
{
  "status": {
    "code": 200
  },
  "response": {
    "categories": [
      {
        "cat": "Taxi",
        "_id": "50b92b585cf34cbc0f000004",
        "subcat": []
      },
      {
        "cat": "Bus",
        "_id": "50b92b585cf34cbc0f000005",
        "subcat": [
          {
            "cat": "Bus Rapid Transit",
            "_id": "50b92b585cf34cbc0f00000b"
          },
          {
            "cat": "Express Bus Service",
            "_id": "50b92b585cf34cbc0f00000a"
          },
          {
            "cat": "Public Transport Bus",
            "_id": "50b92b585cf34cbc0f000009"
          },
          {
            "cat": "Tour Bus",
            "_id": "50b92b585cf34cbc0f000008"
          },
          {
            "cat": "Shuttle Bus",
            "_id": "50b92b585cf34cbc0f000007"
          },
          {
            "cat": "Intercity Bus",
            "_id": "50b92b585cf34cbc0f000006"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "cat": "Rail",
        "_id": "50b92b585cf34cbc0f00000c",
        "subcat": [
          {
            "cat": "Intercity Train",
            "_id": "50b92b585cf34cbc0f000012"
          },
          {
            "cat": "Rapid Transit/Subway",
            "_id": "50b92b585cf34cbc0f000011"
          },
          {
            "cat": "High-speed Rail",
            "_id": "50b92b585cf34cbc0f000010"
          },
          {
            "cat": "Express Train Service",
            "_id": "50b92b585cf34cbc0f00000f"
          },
          {
            "cat": "Passenger Train",
            "_id": "50b92b585cf34cbc0f00000e"
          },
          {
            "cat": "Tram",
            "_id": "50b92b585cf34cbc0f00000d"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have a call to my API that gets me that document (`app.ly/api/v1/stationcategories`). I find this much easier to code with.

In your case you could have something like:

```
      {
        "option": "Breeds",
        "_id": "xxx",
        "suboption": [
          {
            "option": "Arabian",
            "_id": "xxx"
          },
          {
            "option": "Quarter House",
            "_id": "xxx"
          },
          {
            "option": "Saddlebred",
            "_id": "xxx"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "option": "Registrars",
        "_id": "xxx",
        "suboption": [
          {
            "option": "AQHA",
            "_id": "xxx"
          },
          {
            "option": "American Arabians",
            "_id": "xxx"
          }
        ]
      }
```

Whenever you need them, either loop through them, or pull specific options from your collection.

**2. Storing as a static JSON document**

This as @Sergio mentioned, is a viable and more simplistic approach. You can then either have separate docs for separate options, or put them in one document.

- You do lose some flexibility here because you can't reference options by Id (which I prefer because changing option name doesn't affect all your other data).
- Prone to typos (though if you know what you're doing this shouldn't be a problem).
- **For Node.js users**: this might leave you with a headache from `require('../../../options.json')` similar to PHP.

The reader will note that I'm being negative about this approach, it works, but is rather inflexible.
Though we're discouraged from using joins unnecessarily on MongoDB, referencing by ObjectId is sometimes useful and extensible.

An example is if your website becomes popular in one region of the world, and say people from Poland start accounting for say 50% of your site visits. If you decide to add Polish translations. You would need to go back to all your documents, and add Polish names (if exists) to your options. If using **approach 1**, it's as easy as adding a Polish name to your options, and then plucking the Polish name from your options collection at runtime.

*I could only think of 2 options other than storing each option as a collection*

**UPDATE: If someone has positives or negatives for either approach, may you please add them. My bias might be unhelpful to some people as there are benefits to storing static JSON files**

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB is schemaless and also no JOIN is supported.  So you have to move out of the RDBMS and normalization given the fact that this is purely a different kind of database.

Few rules which you can apply while designing as a guidelines.  Of course, you have the choice of keeping it in a separate collection when needed.

**Static Master/Reference Data:**
You have to always embed them in your documents wherever required.  Since the data is not going to be changed, it is not at all bad idea to keep in the same collection.  If the data is too large, group them and store them in a separate collection instead of creating multiple collection for the this master data itself.

***NOTE:**  When embedding the collections as sub-documents, always make sure that you are never going to exceed the 16MB limit.  That is the limit (at this point) for each collection can take in MongoDB.*

**Dynamic Master/Reference Data**
Try to keep them in a separate collection as the master data is tend to change often.

Always remember, **NO join support**, so keep them in a way that you can easily access it without querying the database too many times.

*So there is NO suggested best way, it always changes based on your need and the design can go either way.*